# Oozie: Action notification mail need to be set as high priority

Tags: apache, hadoop, smtp, workflow, oozie

I am new in the Oozie field. I want to set Oozie action email notification set to be high priority. I have checked Oozie documentation and cannot find answer. Any one can help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the email action does not provide for that. A custom extension should do that, please see http://www.infoq.com/articles/ExtendingOozie